# SQL Management Console can't find SQL Server Express 2008 R2 on MacBook Pro Bootcamp

Tags: boot-camp, sql-server-2008

After some problems with "landingpage.exe" errors and a bunch of reinstalls - I had a successful install of SQL Server 2008 R2 on my Macbook Pro 13" Bootcamp partition. SQL Server is showing as an active service in control panel, etc. When I opened the Management Console it could not find the SQL Server, it just shows no local server. Fiddling around with other SQL Server tools I would get "named pipes" errors, which may or may not relate to the lost Server. Has anyone successfully used R2 with Bootcamp and if so what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question in case someone else has this frustrating problem. It was purely a MS issue. On a laptop with local database two problems occurred - first was an error "cannot find landingpage.exe..." - Delete the Microsoft_Corporation folder from location C:\Documents and Settings[USR]\Local Settings\Application Data and that will fix the first installation error.

Next I got an error 40 where the running SQL service could not be found. I finally manually replaced (local) in SQL Management Studio with [machine_name]\SQLEXPRESS and that worked. What fooled me is that the SQLEXPRESS name did not appear after a browse for instances - always before all available SQLSERVER instances had been listed. Anyway, typing in the name worked for me.